# When talking to a USB device, WriteFile sometimes hangs

Tags: windows, winapi, usb, driver

I'm writing a windows utility that communicates to a a USB Device. The driver is a custom driver, supplied by Analog Devices (the manufacturer of the controller chip used in the device).

I've adapted one of their example Windows apps for communcicating with the device. Communication is done via named pipes, and can be synchronous or asynchronous. The problem I've found during testing is that calls to the WriteFile api function can sometimes fail to return if the device is switched off during a write (the device has a hard power switch). The same thing is observed using async or sync calls - I see no timeout happening when using aysnc.

After this has happened, I need to restart my app, as the thread dealing with USB communications is hung.

Is there a way I can prevent the WriteFile from failing to return in this case?

Thanks
Tom Davies.

Comment: You should ask the question at the device vendors support forum

Comment: Of course, but I often find I get a much faster response here!

Answer (score 0):

You can [cancel IO operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363789%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) using [CancelSynchronousIo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363794%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [CancelIoEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363792%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You could do this if you detect that your comm thread is unexpectedly blocking during writes.

Possible deal breakers:

- Available only in Windows Vista and newer
- Driver has to support cancellation